# Simple makefile. Why is .exe being created and then deleted by make?

Tags: c++, makefile, antivirus

There's another question from me where netbeans doesn't create a .exe but there's no error output from netbeans. This is still unresolved. Since I was asked to compile this project without the IDE but only with 'make' and I had never done it before, I created this simple program in order to learn about makefiles.

```
//main.cpp
int main() { 
  int i = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

My makefile looks like this:

```
project000: main.o
    g++ -Wall main.o -o project000

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o project000
```

When I go into the project directory and execute 'make', the .o file is created and I can see the project000.exe being created and then deleted ! So I checked if the 'clean' part of the makefile is executed every time by shortening the makefile to

```
project000: main.o
    g++ -Wall main.o -o project000

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp
```

but the same thing happens. The .exe is being created and then deleted.

Anyone ?

Output of 'make -d' (may not include the beginning, since my prompt had too few lines when I ran it)

```
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.l'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Make
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.l'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.l,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.l'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.l,v
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.l'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.l'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.l'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.l'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.l'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.w'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Make
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.w'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.w,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.w'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.w,v
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.w'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.w'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.w'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.w'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.w'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Mak
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.cc'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cc'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.cc,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cc'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.cc,v
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cc'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.cc'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cc'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.cc'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cc'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.c
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.C'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.C'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.C,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.C'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.C,v'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.C'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.C'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.C'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.C'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.C'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.C
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.cpp'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.cpp,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.cpp,
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.cpp'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.c
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.p'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.web'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.p'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.p,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.p'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.p,v'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.p'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.p'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.p'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.p'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.p'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.p
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.web'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Make
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.web'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.web,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.web'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.web
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.web'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.web
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.web'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.web'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.web'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.f'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.F'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.r'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.f'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.f,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.f'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.f,v'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.f'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.f'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.f'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.f'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.f'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.f
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.F'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Make
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.F'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.F,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.F'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.F,v
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.F'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.F'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.F'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.F'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.F'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.r'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Make
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Ma
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.r'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.r,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.r'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.r,v
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.r'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.r'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.r'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.r'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.r'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Make
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Make
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.s'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.S'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.s'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.s,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.s'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.s,v'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.s'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.s'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.s'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.s'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.s'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.s
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.S'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Make
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.S,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.S,v
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.S'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.S'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.S'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Make
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.mod'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makef
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.mod,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.mod,
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.mod'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.mod'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.mod'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.m
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite `Makef
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.sh'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `Makefi
 Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `Makefile.sh,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.  
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.sh,v'
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/Makefile.sh'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.Makefile.sh'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `Makefile.sh'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.Makefile.sh
 No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
 Updating goal targets....
 Considering target file `project000.exe'.
 File `project000.exe' does not exist.
 Considering target file `main.o'.
 Considering target file `main.cpp'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `main.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `main.cpp,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/main.cpp,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/main.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.main.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.main.cpp'
 Looking for a case-insensitive implicit rule f
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `main.cpp,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/main.cpp,v'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/main.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `s.main.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `main.cpp'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.main.cpp'
 No implicit rule found for `main.cpp'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `main.cp
 No need to remake target `main.cpp'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `main.o'.
 Prerequisite `main.cpp' is older than target `ma
 No need to remake target `main.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `project000.
 Must remake target `project000.exe'.
 g++ -Wall main.o -o project000.exe
 Putting child 0x0a020398 (project000.exe) PID 5840
 Live child 0x0a020398 (project000.exe) PID 5840
 Reaping winning child 0x0a020398 PID 5840
 Removing child 0x0a020398 PID 5840 from chain.
 Successfully remade target file `project000.exe'.
```

Make -Rrd output

```
 This program built for i686-pc-msys
 Reading makefiles...
 Reading makefile `Makefile'...
 Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
 Looking for a case-insensitive implicit rule for `Makefile'.
 No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
 Updating goal targets....
 Considering target file `project000.exe'.
 File `project000.exe' does not exist.
 Considering target file `main.o'.
 Considering target file `main.cpp'.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `main.cpp'.
 Looking for a case-insensitive implicit rule for `main.cpp'.
 No implicit rule found for `main.cpp'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `main.cpp'.
 No need to remake target `main.cpp'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `main.o'.
 Prerequisite `main.cpp' is older than target `main.o'.
 No need to remake target `main.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `project000.exe'.
 Must remake target `project000.exe'.
 g++ -Wall main.o -o project000.exe
 Putting child 0x0a01a270 (project000.exe) PID 6796 on the chain.
 Live child 0x0a01a270 (project000.exe) PID 6796
 Reaping winning child 0x0a01a270 PID 6796
 Removing child 0x0a01a270 PID 6796 from chain.
 Successfully remade target file `project000.exe'.
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `project000` by `project000.exe` ?

Comment: Paste the result of `make -d` here.

Comment: Are you running make in a directory that contains files other than your Makefile and main.cpp?

Comment: Yes I did. Deleting all other files except main.cpp and Makefile and running make again did give the same result, though.

Comment: Try `make -Rrd`, that should remove the builtin rules, making the debug output a lot shorter and more readable.

Comment: You don't happen to have a virus scanner or other over-eager filesystem-monitoring application active, do you? Try running the `g++` commands yourself to rule out `make` as the culprit.

Comment: I added the smaller debug output. Running g++ command g++ -Wall main.o -o project000 does the same. Exe is created, then deleted.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: You were right. My Avast Antivir was in silent mode and it put every new .exe in quarantine without notifying me. The other problem I had (other thread) was caused by this, too. Thank you all !

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that turns out to have nothing to do with programming (or either of its tags). It is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I disagree. Why shouldn't someone run into the same problem (exe is being created, then deleted) because of a virus scanner ? I added another tag (antivirus).

Comment: @Earnie: Can you please add "solution" to your question so that readers can resolve the problem without reading the comments here? Or simply post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avast Antivir was in silent mode and it put every new .exe in quarantine without notifying me. That's why the .exe was instantly deleted after its creation.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer once you are allowed to.

Comment: Counting the hours ;-)